# Are ul, li and divs semantic correct for a HTML5 grid layout?

Tags: html, grid

For example. You have a portfolio page where you have 6 x 6 images in a grid format. Usually, I see a lot of people doing that using `ul -> li` and in some cases, just a bunch of `divs`. So, my question is semantically speaking, is there a right way to define a HTML5 grid layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything that deals with semantics seems to be very up in the air in the HTML5 community.  We can only look at what the spec has to say about specific elements.

> The `<ul>` element represents the unordered list.
>
> The ul element represents a list of items, where the order of the items is not important — that is, where changing the order would not materially change the meaning of the document.

HTML lists are groups of related items.

> The `<div>` element has no special meaning at all.
>
> When no other element is suitable, the div element is used as an element of last resort. Otherwise, it leads to poor accessibility for reader.

The `<div>` represents its children.

Thus it depends on the specific content.  `<ul> -> <li>` should be used for lists of related items.  There may be other semantic tags to use as well depending on the circumstance.

I got most of my information from http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/HTML/Elements

Comment: @Daniel the answer is "it depends."